# Use of auto start feature of IIS 7.5 with .NET 3.5 WCF service

Tags: wcf, iis, appfabric

I have been reading documentation about the new features that IIS 7.5 offers regarding the auto start feature of WCF web services.

As far as I have understood, this feature is only available for WCF web services developed under .NET 4.0, but we were wondering if there could be any workaround or tweak in the configuration of a .NET 3.5 WCF web service to take advantage of this auto start feature of IIS. Now we cannot afford upgrading our web service to .NET 4.0.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Jose Antonio Arroba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature of ASP.NET 4.0 and not WCF, so an upgrade is necessary. Sorry to disappoint you. One more argument for the management to speed up the upgrade, because I am sure it's political and not technical. If it was technical you would already be happily running .NET 4.0.

Comment: I was suspecting that only a feature for 4.0, but as I couldn´t read it explicitly on the documentation, I wanted to be sure. Many thanks for your answer, Darin.